# Excel Concatenate month

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I am trying to take the following value and making it into a date format of dd-MMM-yy

For example: `110412` turns into `04-NOV-12`

My formula as of right now is:

```
(CONCATENATE(MID(E14,3,2),"-",(TEXT(LEFT(E14,2),"MMM")),"-",RIGHT(E14,2)))
```

It is giving me `04-Jan-12`.

Please note that I would like the month to be in all caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the "UPPER(foo)" function as a wrapper to make the result all caps.

```
UPPER((CONCATENATE(MID(E14,3,2),"-",(TEXT(LEFT(E14,2),"MMM")),"-",RIGHT(E14,2))))
```

or better still:

```
=MID(E14,3,2)&"-"&UPPER(TEXT(DATE(MID(E14,5,2),MID(E14,1,2),MID(E14,3,2)),"MMM"))&"-"&RIGHT(E14,2)
```

Comment: I want to turn 110412 to 04-NOV-12, but rather it is showing 04-JAN-12.

Comment: I'm using http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129073 to provide you with an elegant solution

Comment: Corrected with working solution. I'm sure it can be edited/neatened a little but the way I've presented it allows you to reuse the `Text` (you could just put dummy integers for year and day to simplify the formula)